# Updating background bounds

Tags: android, background, android-custom-view

I'm trying to update the background bounds of an EditText view such that the end result resembles something like this...

```
+----------------+
|  Empty Space   |
|                |
| +------------+ |
| | Background | |
| +------------+ |
+----------------+
```

My current approach is to obtain the background in `onLayout` and simply update the bounds...

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
  ...
  getBackground().setBounds(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom);
}
```

However, this doesn't work at all. The bounds are being applied, but when it draws, it doesn't change. The closest i've come to, is changing the bounds in `onDraw`, however, it will initially be drawn at it's original place, an then immediately be re-drawn to it's new position... How can I reliably change the background bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research, the only way I was able to solve this, is to create an intermediary Drawable (man in the middle) and delegate all public methods to the actual Drawable. Then override `setBounds` to set whatever value I want...

```
public class MyCustomView extends EditText {

  @Override
  public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    super.setBackground(new IntermediaryDrawable(background));
  }

  ...

  private class IntermediaryDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Drawable theRealDrawable;

    public IntermediaryDrawable(Drawable source) {
      theRealDrawable = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
      theRealDrawable.setBounds(left, 100, right, bottom);
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Pretty hacky. If anyone comes across this with a better solution, please share.

Comment: Another way would be overriding the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method from `View` class and set the bounds before drawing the background which, IMO, is also pretty messed up. Your method is probably the best way to do this.